# getting access to Wi-Fi internet while being on a Ubuntu lve CD

Tags: wireless

I have a problem with my Windows 7 laptop that won't start. I need to fix my D: drive partition but to  do so, I would have to get access to Wi-Fi Internet and I'm on the Ubuntu Live CD USB stick and so far, I couldn't get access to Wi-Fi Internet. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

The Wi-Fi connection indicator is the one that looks like a triangle on the top right corner of the screen. Click it and it should show the available Wi-Fi networks in your area.

Comment: If  I hover over that triangle,a drop box shows and "Wired Network disconnected" and Connection information are "greyed out".  Then, a little later, I get another box "restricted drivers are available" I click on "install drivers" and then "activate" at the "Broadband STA wireless driver" box. Then, I get "wireless net work available", go to the "Network menu". I go to the "home folder" and click on it then click on "Browse Net...." and I get to an icon "Windows Network". I click on it and I get message error: "Unable to mount loacation. Failed to retrieve share list from server". Huh!

Comment: Well...I went back to hover over the triangle and now, the wi-fi networks available are showing. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that. It seems you have exotic wifi hardware here. Ubuntu support for Windows (SMB) network isn't really mature yet, hence the message. Would you mind marking this question as solved?